# On Mac OS 10.8 I recompile PHP with new modules, but php -m doesnt shouw them

Tags: php, php-extension, recompile

I have recompiled PHP 5.4.13 (This is not the PHP install that comes with Mac OS 10.8, this is a build that I did to upgrade PHP on my Mac) with some new modules like geoIP, WDDX and few other extentions, but its not showing up when I do php -m, it shows the same old build.

Even if I do a php -v it shows old build details such as build date and time of the build. Means my make install really didn't worked. But no errors or what so ever when I run make install.

My ./configure command is

```
./configure 
--prefix=/usr  \
--mandir=/usr/share/man/ \
--infodir=/usr/share/info/ \
--extension-dir=ext \
--enable-dependency-tracking \
--sysconfdir=/private/etc/ \
--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs  \
--enable-cli \
--with-config-file-path=/etc/ \
--with-libxml \
--with-openssl \
--with-kerberos=/usr/ \
--with-zlib \
--enable-bcmath \
--with-bz2 \
--enable-calendar \
--disable-cgi \
--with-curl \
--enable-dba \
--enable-ndbm=/usr/ \
--enable-exif \
--enable-fpm \
--enable-ftp \
--with-gd \
--with-freetype-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-78~13/Root/usr/local \
--with-jpeg-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-78~13/Root/usr/local \
--with-png-dir=/BinaryCache/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-78~13/Root/usr/local \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-icu-dir=/usr/ \
--with-iodbc=/usr/ \
--with-ldap=/usr/ \
--with-ldap-sasl=/usr/ \
--with-libedit=/usr/ \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-mbregex \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--without-pear \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock \
--with-readline=/usr/ \
--enable-shmop \
--with-snmp=/usr/ \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sqlite-utf8 \
--enable-suhosin \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--with-tidy \
--enable-wddx \
--with-xmlrpc \
--with-iconv-dir=/usr/ \
--with-xsl=/usr/ \
--enable-zend-multibyte \
--enable-zip \
--with-pcre-regex=/usr/ \
--with-pgsql=/usr/ \
--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/ \
--with-geoip=geoip
```

And this is my php -m output

```
 [PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
```

[Zend Modules]

This is what which php has to says,

```
/opt/local/bin/php
```

This is what whereis php says,

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the operation system? Some Linux distro (I have Ubuntu in mind) has a penchant for stashing copies of php cli in obscure locations.

Comment: This is on Mac OS 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Comment: Do you see the executable in php-5.4.13/sapi/cli?

Comment: You mean the dir in extracted php installation? Yes its there

Comment: And which `php` bin are you executing? What do you get when you execute on the terminal `which php`?

Comment: If it's there, then it has compiled correctly. Run it, with the `-m` to check that your extensions are there. Then take a look at `/usr/bin/php` to see if it's the same file. That's where the make script should have copied the file. Do a `whereis php` to see if that's the file getting executed.